# Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault on Win 10 while training the model (faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco) for object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I was trying to use the faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28 for my first object detection project. I was trying to train the model, and got this error. Before this error occurred, I was struggling with 'abs' being not found. I reinstalled tensorflow, and somehow it worked.

This is the code that I ran on cmd. If I need to post what's in train.py or any code that I should have posted here, let me know.

`(tf1.12) C:\Users\EuisanKim\Desktop\tf1.12\model\research\object_detection>python legacy/train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config`

C:\Users\EuisanKim\Anaconda3\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:516: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\EuisanKim\Anaconda3\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:517: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\EuisanKim\Anaconda3\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:518: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\EuisanKim\Anaconda3\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:519: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\EuisanKim\Anaconda3\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:520: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\EuisanKim\Anaconda3\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
C:\Users\EuisanKim\Anaconda3\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:541: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
C:\Users\EuisanKim\Anaconda3\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:542: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
C:\Users\EuisanKim\Anaconda3\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:543: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
C:\Users\EuisanKim\Anaconda3\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:544: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
C:\Users\EuisanKim\Anaconda3\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:545: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
C:\Users\EuisanKim\Anaconda3\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\tensorflow_stub\dtypes.py:550: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
W0829 08:28:04.658330 10092 lazy_loader.py:50]
The TensorFlow contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.
For more information, please see:
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/addons
  * https://github.com/tensorflow/io (for I/O related ops)
If you depend on functionality not listed there, please file an issue.

W0829 08:28:04.851034 10092 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\Users\EuisanKim\Desktop\tf1.12\model\research\slim\nets\inception_resnet_v2.py:373: The name tf.GraphKeys is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys instead.

W0829 08:28:04.878998 10092 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From C:\Users\EuisanKim\Desktop\tf1.12\model\research\slim\nets\mobilenet\mobilenet.py:397: The name tf.nn.avg_pool is deprecated. Please use tf.nn.avg_pool2d instead.

W0829 08:28:04.907918 10092 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From legacy/train.py:55: The name tf.logging.set_verbosity is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity instead.

W0829 08:28:04.908879 10092 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From legacy/train.py:55: The name tf.logging.INFO is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.logging.INFO instead.

W0829 08:28:04.913866 10092 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From legacy/train.py:184: The name tf.app.run is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.app.run instead.

W0829 08:28:04.916857 10092 deprecation.py:323] From C:\Users\EuisanKim\Anaconda3\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py:251: main (from **main**) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use object_detection/model_main.py.
W0829 08:28:04.917856 10092 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From legacy/train.py:90: The name tf.gfile.MakeDirs is deprecated. Please use tf.io.gfile.makedirs instead.

W0829 08:28:04.920847 10092 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From legacy/train.py:107: The name tf.gfile.Copy is deprecated. Please use tf.io.gfile.copy instead.

Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x0000276c (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\EuisanKim\Anaconda3\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 486 in copy_v2
  File "C:\Users\EuisanKim\Anaconda3\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 469 in copy
  File "legacy/train.py", line 108 in main
  File "C:\Users\EuisanKim\Anaconda3\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 324 in new_func
  File "C:\Users\EuisanKim\Anaconda3\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251 in _run_main
  File "C:\Users\EuisanKim\Anaconda3\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 300 in run
  File "C:\Users\EuisanKim\Anaconda3\envs\tf1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40 in run
  File "legacy/train.py", line 184 in

What I did before running the code above are:

1) Annotating the data
  - I was using different sizes of pictures (Could this lead to this error?)

2) Creating the record files, label map file, and etc that are necessary for training

I just started to learn programming. I don't know much about what's happening with this problem. Please, help me. Thank you.

Comment: You should the code that is throwing that error. You should also try to explain what you are trying to do with more context. Check the ["Help Center"](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information about how to write a good question.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. All I did was preparing data and changing the path for the configuration. I will try to edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to .

1. An import issue is there
2. Code being written in python2 but running in python3

Do these steps to remove this error,

1. Put `from object_detection import eval_util` as last import in file `model_lib.py` under `research/object_detection`
2. Wrap range() objects with list() in API code (to support python3)